# Which spectra have a universal connective quotient?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stable-homotopy, adjoint-functors

Consider the homotopy category $\mathrm{hoSp}$ of spectra. It has a full subcategory $\mathrm{hoSp}_{\geq 0}$ of connective spectra, equivalently of infinite loop spaces, equivalently $E_\infty$-group spaces.

The inclusion $\mathrm{hoSp}_{\geq 0} \hookrightarrow \mathrm{hoSp}$ has a right adjoint, sending a spectrum $T$ to its connective cover $T\langle0\rangle$. In other words, for any connective spectrum $A$, we have
$$ [A, T] = [A, T\langle 0\rangle].$$
I'm wondering about intermediate categories $\mathrm{hoSp}_{\geq 0} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{C} \hookrightarrow \mathrm{hoSp}$ for which the inclusion $\mathrm{hoSp}_{\geq 0} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{C}$ also has a left adjoint. Explicitly: for which spectra $T$ is there a connective spectrum $T'$ such that
$$[T,A] = [T', A]$$
for all connective $A$? This $T'$ would be some sort of universal "quotient" of $T$ that quotients it down to being connective.

Dually, I can consider the full subcategory $\mathrm{hoSp}_{\leq 0} \hookrightarrow \mathrm{hoSp}$ of coconnective spectra. This inclusion has a left adjoint given by the truncation $T \mapsto \tau_{\leq 0}T$. On which intermediate category does this inclusion also have a right adjoint?

I am also interested in variations of these questions, e.g. working with the $(\infty,1)$-categories rather than their homotopy categories, or looking at the inclusion of spectra with homotopy in some bounded range $[0,n]$ (perhaps $n=0$, say) among spectra with homotopy bounded on only one side, or looking at spectra with some finiteness built in.

---

**Codicil:** The accepted answer below resolves the $\infty$-categorical variation of this question. Since the homotopy-categorical version is different, I have posted it as [new question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444845/).

Comment: I think that $[H\mathbb{Q}[-2], A] = 0 = [A, H\mathbb{Q}[-2]]$ for every connective $A$. Thus, you can add $H\mathbb{Q}[-2]$ to $\mathrm{ho}(\mathrm{Sp}_{\geq 0})$ and then have as your connective quotient just killing it again. This works, however, not if you take the $\infty$-category since $\mathrm{Map}(H\mathbb{Q}[-2], A)$ certainly can be non-trivial.

Comment: If you do the $\infty$-category version (as @LennartMeier's comment suggests might be appropriate), then I believe that the maximal subcategory $C$ that has such an adjoint is the category of $T$ whose integral homology is concentrated in nonnegative degrees.

Comment: Moreover, for such T the adjoint is given by the "Hℤ-nilpotent completion of T" in the sense of Bousfield's paper "Localization of spectra with respect to homology".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is about the $\infty$-categorical variant. This is a fancy way to say: on *spaces* of maps, the natural map
$$
Map(T',A) \to Map(T,A)
$$
is an equivalence for any connective $A$. Note that for any bounded-below spectrum $B$, we can use $Map(-,B) \simeq \Omega^n Map(-,\Sigma^n B)$ to conclude that the natural map above is an equivalence for $B$ as well, and hence by taking homotopy classes of maps we get that
$$
[T',B] \to [T,B]
$$
is an equivalence for any bounded-below $B$.

---

I first claim: a map $T \to T'$ induces an equivalence $[T', B] \to [T,B]$ for all bounded-below $B$ if and only if it is an integral homology isomorphism.

To see that this is necessary:

Consider $B$ of the form $K(Q,n)$ for $Q$ an injective abelian group -- these are bounded-below. Then the universal coefficient theorem implies that the natural map
$$
Hom(H_n(T'), Q) \to Hom(H_n(T), Q)
$$
is isomorphic to the natural map
$$
H^n(T', Q) \cong [T', K(Q,n)] \to H^n(T,Q) \cong [T, K(Q,n)],
$$
and hence is an isomorphism. If this is true for all injective abelian groups $Q$, for a generic abelian group $M$ we can apply it to an injective resolution of $M$ and find that the natural map
$$
Hom(H_n(T'), M) \to Hom(H_n(T), M)
$$
is an isomorphism.

To see that this is sufficient:

Suppose we have a map $T \to T'$ which is an integral homology isomorphism, and consider the class of spectra $B$ such that $[T',B] \to [T,B]$ is an isomorphism.

- This class contains Eilenberg-Mac Lane spectra, by the universal coefficient theorem.
- This class is closed under fibers. If $B' \to B \to B''$ is a fiber sequence of spectra, then we get long exact sequences upon applying $[T,-]$ or $[T',-]$, and if the maps $[T',B] \to [T,B]$ and $[T',B''] \to [T',B'']$ are isomorphisms then so is $[T',B'] \to [T,B']$ by the five-lemma.
- This class is closed under spectra that have finitely many nonzero homotopy groups, by inductively applying this to the fiber sequences $K(\pi_n B, n) \to P_n B \to P_{n-1} B$ in their Postnikov tower.
- This class is closed under products.
- This class is closed under homotopy limits of towers. If we have a tower $\dots \to B_2 \to B_1 \to B_0$ of objects in this class, then the homotopy limit is part of a fiber sequence
  $$
  holim (B_i) \to \prod B_i \xrightarrow{1-\text{shift}} \prod B_i
  $$
  and so the homotopy limit is in the class.
- This class contains all bounded-below spectra, because any bounded-below $B$ is the homotopy limit of its Postnikov tower $\dots \to P_2 B \to P_1 B \to P_0 B$, and the individual $P_n B$ all have only finitely many nonzero homotopy groups.

---

Now I claim: the collection of $T$ for which such a connective $T'$ exists consists of the spectra $T$ such that the integral homology $H_*(T)$ is concentrated in nonnegative degrees. This is necessary: because $T \to T'$ is an integral homology isomorphism, the isomorphism $H_n(T) \to H_n(T')$ forces $H_n(T) \cong H_n(T') \cong 0$ for $n < 0$.

Suppose that $H_* T = 0$ in negative degrees. An equivalent formulation is that the smash product $H\Bbb Z \wedge T$ is connective. If this is true, then we can form the $H\Bbb Z$-Adams tower. Briefly, construct a fiber sequence $J \to \Bbb S \to H\Bbb Z$ (hence $J$ is 0-connected) and form the tower
$$
\Bbb S/J \wedge T \leftarrow \Bbb S/J^2 \wedge T \leftarrow \Bbb S/J^3 \wedge T \leftarrow \dots
$$
The homotopy limit $T'$ is called the $H\Bbb Z$-nilpotent completion of $T$, and it has a natural map $T \to T'$.

Something special happens in this case, however, that I'll just briefly describe. The associated graded, in degree $p$, is $\Bbb S/J \wedge J^{p} \wedge T \simeq (H\Bbb Z \wedge T) \wedge J^p$. This is $p$-connected because $J^p$ is $p$-connected and $H\Bbb Z \wedge T$ is connective. As a result, by induction this nilpotent completion is connective. Moreover, smashing with $H\Bbb Z$ can be moved inside the homotopy limit because of this connectivity growth, and the map $H\Bbb Z \wedge T \to H\Bbb Z \wedge T'$ turns out to be a weak equivalence (true for Adams towers whenever smashing can be moved inside the limit); so $T \to T'$ is a homology isomorphism.

---

As a note, for this to happen we need for the fiber of $T \to T'$ to have trivial homology; this is impossible unless it is contractible or it is unbounded below. This is certainly interesting but carries it outside the usual library of basic examples.

Comment: Cool! So the class of $T$ for which such a $T'$ exists includes the $H\mathbb Z$-acyclic spectra. I wonder what $K(n)'$ is? (Nevermind -- if $X$ is $H\mathbb Z$-acyclic, then $X' = 0$.)

Comment: Very neat. It turns out that the example that motivated my question is not unbounded below, and thinking more about it, I think the adjunction only holds in the homotopy category, and not at the level of spaces. So I have accepted this excellent answer, and will repost the homotopy version at another question.